# Electron Desktop app that can open web URL using proxy ip address

Tags: javascript, node.js, desktop-application, electron, nativeapplication

i have just discovered about electron js. **i want to create desktop app which can help to open website with proxy server**. i have tried following code, please help me.and please comment any working example.

```
const electron = require('electron');
const app = electron.app;
var BrowserWindow = require('browser-window');

electron.crashReporter.start();

var mainWindow = null;

app.on('window-all-closed', function() {
    if (process.platform != 'darwin') {
        app.quit();
    }
});

app.on('ready', function() {

    // without proxy simple
    //var win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600, show: false });
    //win.on('closed', function() {
    //    win = null;
    //});
    //
    //win.loadURL('https://www.panduboys.com');
    //win.show();

    var win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 });
    win.loadUrl("http://www.panduboys.com");

    var session = win.webContents.session
    session.setProxy("http=190.98.162.22:8080", function() {
        console.log('done proxy kind of things');
    });
});
```

Comment: did u find solution for this

Comment: no i didn't find solution

Comment: please check this I found a solution for that using pac file . Just update the PAC file with your proxy it will automatically get updated to your app/webview . https://discuss.atom.io/t/how-connect-to-proxy-in-electron-webview/29604

Comment: ok thank, i will review it.